# How do I use the Comparable module to write Ruby code that compares song lengths?

Tags: ruby, comparable

```
class Song
  include Comparable
  attr_accessor :song_name
  def <=>(other)
    @song_name.length <=> other.length
  end

  def initialize(song_name)
    @song_name = song_name
    @song_name_length = song_name.length
  end
end

a = Song.new('Rock around the clock')
b = Song.new('Bohemian Rhapsody')
c = Song.new('Minute Waltz')

puts a < b
puts b >= c
puts c > a
puts a.between?(c,b)
```

Here's what I have so far. I'm trying to write code that compares the length of song names.

Comment: You're trying to write code to compare String lengths, not song lengths.

Answer (score 2):

Fix your compare primitive so it compares against the like attribute of the other:

```
  def <=>(other)
    song_name.length <=> other.song_name.length
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two things wrong. You need a semicolon after `class Song` and you need to compare the length of the `@song_name` with that of the `other`, not the `other` itself. You also do not need `attr_accessor`. Change it to `attr_reader`.

```
class Song; include Comparable
  attr_reader :song_name
  def <=>(other)
    @song_name.length <=> other.song_name.length
  end

  def initialize(song_name)
    @song_name = song_name
    @song_name_length = song_name.length
  end
end
```

Comment: It would be more idiomatic if `include Comparable` is on the following line.

Comment: What is the difference between attr_accessor and attr_reader?

Comment: And is the semi-colon after class Song necessary?

Comment: `attr_accessor` creates both the setter and the getter. `attr_reader` creates only the getter. It is necessary if you want to put them on the same line, which it was at some time in the edit.